# How to explain "until after " correctly?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Example sentences:

1. He is not available until after 12 pm.
2. He is available until after 12 pm.

What is the different meaning of the two sentences? So, when exactly is he available?  I tried to find some examples, but I still cannot understand what is the correct meaning for both.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence means "He will not be available before 12PM" or "He will be available from 12PM onwards" In other words, 12PM must have passed before he is available.
The second sentence is not good English. It should be either "He is available until 12PM (but not afterwards)" or "He is available after 12PM (but not before)"
"until after" just doesn't work in this context.

Comment: To my ear the second sentence, though a bit unusual, is okay à la @gotube’s reading:  He is at present available, and he will remain available until some moment that is as yet undetermined excepting that it will be later than 12 PM.  To put it differently, his availability runs continuously from now up to a point at some time past noon.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum That's how I would have read it as well (and also agree it's unusual). A better phrasing would be "_He is available until at least 12 pm._".

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum OK, I concede you can interpret it like that, but I would say that you have to stop and think what it was trying to say and there are much clearer ways of putting it. IMHO "until" means "up to" or "before" whilst "after" means just that and at a first reading they sort of contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

"Until" means "*continuously from now to the given time*".

So your first sentence means roughly, "*He is *unavailable*, and will become available only after 12 pm*".

Your second sentence just means the opposite, roughly, "*He is *available* now, but will stop being available some time after 12 pm*".